# Odd / Even posts add class minus first post

Tags: php, css, query

I'm using the following to add specific classes to my odd/even posts but I also need to add a class to all posts except the first one. Is there a quick, semantic way to do this minus the first post?

```
<?php $homenews_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=4' ); ?>

            <?php while ($homenews_query -> have_posts()) : $homenews_query -> the_post(); ?>
            <?php if ($homenews_query->current_post % 2 == 0): ?>
<!-- stuff here -->
<?php else: ?>
<!-- stuff here -->    
<?php endif ?>

    <?php 
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

I've tried various ways to do this--mostly with jQuery (addClass and removeClass) and it's not been working for me.

TIA!

Comment: Have you tried adding an extra conditional `if ($homenews_query->current_post != 0)`

Comment: You don't even need to add a class if you just want to style them. You can use pseudo-elements, such as `.class:first-child` for styling the first element, and `.class:nth-child(2n)` - `.class:nth-child(2n+1)` for styling odd-even elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in multiple ways, but you will need something commom to all posts, exemple:

```
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
<div class="post"></div>
```

then in your **css**:

```
.post:not(:first-child) {
  // add the rules of the class you wanted to add
}
```

Just select all elements except the first-child of posts with the class `post` and add the rules of the class you wanted to add.

You also can do with **js/jquery**:

```
$('.post:not(:first-child)').addClass('myclass');
```

It's the same logic as with css, but if you wnat to add a separate class you can do it.

or you can do with **php**:

```
<?php $count = 0 ?>
<?php while ($homenews_query -> have_posts()) : $homenews_query -> the_post(); ?>

<?php if ($count != 0): ?>
  <!-- stuff here -->
<?php endif ?>

<?php if ($homenews_query->current_post % 2 == 0): ?>
  <!-- stuff here -->
<?php else: ?>
  <!-- stuff here -->    
<?php endif ?>

<?php 
  $count++;
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I know that the first post, is the one in the `index 0` so a just check if the count is != 0.

or simpler, you have an attribute called `current_post` just check if you're not in the first post, like this:

```
<?php while ($homenews_query -> have_posts()) : $homenews_query -> the_post(); ?>

<?php if ($homenews_query->current_post != 0): ?>
  <!-- stuff here -->
<?php endif ?>

<?php if ($homenews_query->current_post % 2 == 0): ?>
  <!-- stuff here -->
<?php else: ?>
  <!-- stuff here -->    
<?php endif ?>
<?php 
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

**Edit: I posted with the inverse logic, fixed now.**

Comment: I ended up using the jQuery to removeClass instead of add.

Comment: @JusticeIsCheap - Seems a bit strange to use jQuery for something you can easily accomplish via PHP for anyone else looking at the code it won't be obvious how the classes are being added/removed. Of course is this is a project just for you that's fine, but if anyone else is going to see/edit/access the project best to keep your code in one place.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing is to add a counter variable to your loop. But also be sure to add a posts exists check to prevent issues if no posts are found and I highly recommend using good commenting and syntax - it's a good habit ;)

Here is an example of the modified code:

```
<?php
// Query posts
$homenews_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=4' );

// If posts are found do stuff
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

    // Define counter
    $count = 0;

    // Loop through posts
    while ( $homenews_query->have_posts() ) : $homenews_query->the_post();

        // Add to counter for each entry
        $count ++;

        // Define default classname for entry
        $class = 'entry';

        // Add class name to all excerpt the first
        if ( 1 !== $count ) {
            $class .= ' first-post';
        }

        // Add odd/even classes
        $class .= $count % 2 == 0 ? ' even' : ' odd';


    // No posts found
    else: ?>

        <!-- stuff here -->

    <?php endif ?>

    <?php
    // End loop
    endwhile;

    // Reset post data to prevent query conflicts
    wp_reset_postdata(); 

// End posts check
endif; ?>
```

Comment: This is the inverse of what I'm looking for. I was looking to add the class to all posts but the first.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread the question. I updated the code accordingly ;)

Comment: Thank you! I'll check this out because the jQuery is working in unexpected ways.

Comment: Hi, I wouldn't recommend jQuery. Also because it loads after the HTML has loaded so if you are adding CSS for these classes it will create a "flash".